# Почему происходит движение блоков в iOS

Tags: html, jquery

Всем доброго дня! В первый раз столкнулся с такой проблемой на айфонах http://dropmefiles.com/lq8bu - ссылка на демонстрацию заказчика. Что и от чего не могу понять, может есть люди с опытом и подскажут куда копать. ссылка на репозиторий https://maksimradziuk.github.io/toyokawa/history.html

Comment: к сожалению нет яблока под рукой, но если проблема только на яблоках проявляется, то советую посмотреть в сторону вопроса о верстке под  ретина экраны

Comment: спасибо) хоть что-то. Если получиться отпишу сюда.

Comment: Пока только нашел информацию с проблемой абсолютных значений, т.е. не указывать размеры в px. Но проблема, мне кажется в другом, на странице истории идет динамическое изменение межстрочного интервала, при том что css анимаций и js кода касающихся этого показателя нет. Есть чёткое css правило указывающее высоту межстрочного интервала в px. Может стоит указать его в em, rem и т.п.?

Comment: не уверен, что поможет, но попробуйте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что iOS несмотря ни на что старается сделать текст читабельным изменяя его размер, и межстрочный интервал соответственно, в тех блоках где текст занимает 100%, или очень близко к этому параметру, ширины блока. Решается проблема просто добавлением тестовому блоку:

```
-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-moz-text-size-adjust: 100%;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
```

всем добра и бобра!)